# Need help transferring pine script v2 command to v5 - MA Crossover

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v2

I would like to convert pine script v2 command to v5 version, but i have stuck on this step:

```
plot(cross(sh, ln) ? sh : na, style = cross, linewidth = 4, color = black)

mycol = sh > ln ? lime : red
fill(p1, p2, color = mycol)
```

In v5 i have typed this command, but getting error code:

```
plot(ta.crossover(sh,ln) ? sh : na, style = ta.crossover, linewidth=4, color.black)

mycol = sh > ln ? color.lime : color.red
fill(p1, p2, color = mycol)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `cross` and `crossover` are two different things. `cross` could be both ways whereas `crossover` is just one way cross.

Also `cross` in `style` is a totally different thing and it defines the shape of the plot.

Below code should do it:

```
plot(ta.cross(sh, ln) ? sh : na, style = plot.style_cross, linewidth = 4, color = color.black)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have now resolved and and migrated all to v5:

```
plot(ta.cross(fastMA, slowMA) ? fastMA : na, style = plot.style_cross, linewidth = 4, color = color.black)

mycol = fastMA > slowMA ? color.blue : color.red
fill(p1, p2, color = mycol)
```